# Визуализация функции в plotly с помощью слайдеров

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, plotly

Пытаюсь сделать визуализацию влияния коэффициентов линейной функции на её график в задаче линейной регрессии на подобие того как это делается в desmos
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого использую следующий код в plotly составленный из кусков чужого кода

```py
import pandas as pd                      
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
# Create figure
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=data.Population, y=data.Profit, mode='markers', name='Population&Profit'))

# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in np.arange(0, 2, 0.1):
    x=np.linspace(3, 23, 100)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=step*np.linspace(-4,23,100)+step))


# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)

fig.show()
```

результат в итоге вот такой[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при передвижении слайдера отрисовывается только новая линия, пробовал добавить отрисовку точек внутрь функции с `add_trace`, но это не помогло. Также данная функция по ощущениям не работает как в `desmos` + хотелось бы всё же реализовать так-же слайдеры и для `k` и для `b`.

Если поменять код следующим образом добавив трейс для точек:

```
for step in np.arange(0, 2, 0.1):
    x=np.linspace(3, 23, 100)
    y=step*np.linspace(-4,23,100)+step
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=data.Population, 
            y=data.Profit, 
            mode='markers', 
            name='Population&Profit')
    )
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
            y=y)
    )
```

то результат будет выглядить вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А при изменении позиции слайдера соответственно отрисовываются сначала точки, а потом линия, и последняя перекрывает точки. Если поменять порядок определения, то наоборот точки перекроют линии, то есть нет эффекта наложения.

Пробовал и определять `fig` внутри функции но тогда вообще всё ломается.

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/sliders/ - прям родная документация с примером. смысл в том, что вы отрисовываете все трейсы невидимыми, а потом "включаете" их в зависимости от положения слайдера.

Comment: Как сделать при этом видимым (фоновым) для каждого трейса точки с данными. Линии и правда "включаются". Но только они, а точки исчезают. А мне надо чтобы они были на каждом трейсе. Я пробовал добавить их внутрь функции, но тогда слайдер ломался

Comment: ну так вы приведите свой новый код.

Comment: Добавил в исходный пост

Comment: что значит "нет эффекта наложения" ? точки и линии отображаются одновременно? если да, то не понятно, его вы хотите.

Comment: В том то и дело что не отображаются одновременно. То что выше видно сразу все и линии и точки это до тех пор пока не двигаешь слайдер. Если начать двигать слайдер то попеременно рендерятся сначала точки потом соответствующая линия (а не одновременно, как задуманно)

В первоначальном коде рендерятся только линии, без точек при передвижении слайдера. Одновременного вывода и точек и линии я так и не добился

Comment: ну выложите датасет для воспроизведения

Comment: https://github.com/Elijah-Prisyazhnyuk/question - загрузил ноутбук и датасет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я отредактировал код, пометив изменения комментариями со стрелкой:

```
import pandas as pd                      
import numpy as np
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
data = pd.read_csv('ex1data1.csv', sep=",", header=None)
data.columns = ["Population", "Profit"]  # устанавливаем заголовки
#print(data.head())
#print(data.info())
# Create figure
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=data.Population, y=data.Profit, mode='markers', name='Population&Profit'))

# Add traces, one for each slider step
for step in np.arange(0, 2, 0.1):
#    x=np.linspace(3, 23, 100)
    x=np.linspace(data.Population.min(), data.Population.max(), 100)    #<--- (1)
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=x,
#            y=step*np.linspace(-4,23,100)+step,
            y  = step*np.linspace(data.Profit.min(),data.Profit.max(),100)+step,  #<--- (2)
#            visible='legendonly'
            visible=True if step==1 else False
        )
    )

    
# Create and add slider
steps = []
for i in range(1, len(fig.data)): #<--- (3)
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
    )
    step["args"][0]["visible"][0] = True  # <--- (4)
    step["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

    
sliders = [dict(
    active=10,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders,
    autosize=False,   #<--- 5
)

fig.show()
```

- 1 и 2 - чтобы график не "скакал", желательно давать точные значения
- 3 - range нужно брать не с 0 в данном случае, иначе при слайдере на нуле первая прямая не будет отрисовываться.
- 4 - при каждой отрисовке фигуры нужно всегда отрисовывать точки исходных данных
- 5 - отключил автосайз, опять же, чтобы график меньше прыгал

вот начальная картинка при запуске кода (теперь не выводятся все трейсы сразу, а только выбранный):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот, для примера, картинка при слайдере на "2"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, работает отлично!